# I get this error even for the simplest code: I can't write on file `file.pdf'. \begin{document}

Tags: errors, texstudio, windows, write-file

I have Texstudio and MiKTeX. Everything was working fine and suddenly it didn't. I tried undoing the recent changes and compiled it still no luck. Finally, I wrote a "hello world" code. It couldn't compile it either.  I even tried compiling it after removing adobe pdf viewer from the computer. I uninstalled and reinstalled texstudio. Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried restarting your computer? That removes Windows file handles. Another suggestion: Check file permissions.

Comment: @campa Look at the title.

Comment: Dear campa, i get this error for every tex file i have: I can't write on file `thesis.pdf'. \begin{document}

Comment: Hi, which  MikTeX version are you running? I assume TeXstudio is 2.12.4 since you reinstalled recently

Comment: Close everything and then try to compile a new document in a new folder on the command line.

Comment: Dear TeXnician i tried restarting too. nothing happens.  im logged in as the administrator.

Comment: dear troy. the miktex version is 2.9

Comment: There's been an update on MikTeX last weekend. I'm not sure if it matters, but perhaps you might try running the update wizard if you have not? Do try compiling from the command line though like Ulrike suggested, and see if you still get the error

Comment: @Abishera: You should redo the formats (via `MiKTeX Settings`, `formats` tab).

Comment: @troy and ulrike I updated MiKTeX and tried to compile from the command prompt. I am still getting the same error. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @bernard Thanks for the support. what exactly should I redo in the formats tab?